# How do I do an S3 copy between regions using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

It was far to difficult to figure this out.  It wasn't obvious to me and lots of explanations left out key details.  I will answer this with the solution.  Sorry if it seems obvious to you, but given how many searches and experiments it took me to do this, I think it is quite worthwhile to show others how to do it.

Comment: Also for future reference, documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Thanks John, but that didn't really help me when I was trying to figure this out.  The problems I had were that both that documentation did not give a cross region example, and more importantly, the error message I got when trying to run it seemed to imply that my URIs needed to be modified.  I would have been able to figure it out easily, either the error message was clearer, or if the documentation provided an explicit cross region copy example.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

UPDATE: According to a commenter, the extra parameters I show here may no longer be needed.  I am not currently working with AWS, so I don't have a way to verify it.  Anyway, I didn't change the rest of this post in case it is still needed in some case.

The trick is being explicit about both the source and destination regions.  They might not always be required, but it doesn't hurt to always show them:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://my-source-bucket-in-us-west-2/ \
      s3://my-target-bucket-in-us-east-1/ \
      --recursive --source-region us-west-2 --region us-east-1
```

Or on Windows

```
> aws s3 cp s3://my-source-bucket-in-us-west-2/ ^
          s3://my-target-bucket-in-us-east-1/ ^
          --recursive --source-region us-west-2 --region us-east-1
```

Comment: This appears to be no longer needed. I tried copying data across regions with awscli and it works out of the box, without being explicit about source and destination buckets.

Comment: If your vpc security policies or your customer does not allow cross region access, may need to create a new bucket (you can copy from another as a template) using the console Create new Bucket | Name and region | etc. Then use the supplied command from @solx to populate the contents in the target region. Works great still!

Comment: I observe the same as Anton Evangelatov: simply specifiying `s3://` URLs where the buckets are in different regions worked fine for me with `aws s3 cp`.